# How to correctly inherit std::iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

Guys if I have class like below:

```
template<class T>
class X
{
T** myData_;
public:
class iterator : public iterator<random_access_iterator_tag,/*WHAT SHALL I PUT HERE? T OR T** AND WHY?*/>
{
T** itData_;//HERE I'M HAVING THE SAME TYPE AS MAIN CLASS ON WHICH ITERATOR WILL OPERATE
};
};
```

Questions are in code next to appropriate lines.
Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656345/writing-my-own-implementation-of-stl-like-iterator-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, your value type should be the type of object your container holds.  My guess would be either T or T*, you don't really provide enough information to say.  [See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator/) for an explanation of what the various parameters mean.  The rest can often be left as defaults.

Comment: I know what the various parameters mean, but as I've said to Potatoswatter I need to know if I should put T or T** there.

Comment: As a starting point, your value type should be the type of object your container holds.  I hate to repeat myself, but you still haven't provided any clue as to what that type is.

Comment: the type is T*, I thought that's obvious from class declaration I've provided.

Comment: Then that is your answer.  `std::iterator<random_access_iterator_tag, T*>`

Answer (score -1):

As for the first question, that should be the data type the iterator returns. Presumably `T`.

As for the second, it depends completely upon what your iterator actually does, which isn't definite or obvious from the information given.

Note that `std::iterator` doesn't define any operations for you, it only defines some `typedef`s which you can inherit.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm interested in. I know that std::iterator doesn't define anything for me but in order to have those typedefs defined correctly I must know what shall I put as a type.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you just really want to learn this stuff, I'd suggest using Boost.Iterator

Comment: Boost.Iterator doesn't really prevent you from having to learn anything except how to properly handle the various operators.  You still have to understand how iterators work before you can properly implement one.